# Editar y eliminar datos de base de datos sqlite a través de un menú desplegable en un listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy realizando una aplicación la cual tiene un listview que se alimenta de una base de datos sqlite, en el listview agregue un botón que aparece en todas sus filas y que al oprimirlo muestra un menú desplegable con las opciones de eliminar y editar. mi pregunta es ¿como puedo hacer que al oprimir este boton que se encuentra en la clase adapter del listview se realicen las acciones correspondientes? se como hacerlo desde el mainActivity o un fragment  pero no desde una clase.

gracias

fragment

```
package com.example.estudiantes;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class asignaturas extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView Recycler;
    ListView ListViewPersonas;
    ArrayList<String>ListaInformacion;
    ArrayList<atributos>ListaAtributos;
    EditText asignatura;

    ConeccionSqliteHelper conn;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_asignaturas,container,false);

        ListViewPersonas = (ListView) vista.findViewById (R.id.lista_asignaturas);


        conn = new ConeccionSqliteHelper(getActivity(), "bd_usuarios", null, 1);

        ConsultarListaPersonas();

        return vista;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        onclick();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Alertdialog para agregar tareas


    public void onclick() {


        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogo, null);
        asignatura = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.camponombre);

        mBuilder.setTitle("Nueva tarea");
        mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Guardar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                registrarUsuarios();
                ConsultarListaPersonas();

            }
        });

        mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });


        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }

    // Agregar tareas

    private void registrarUsuarios() {


        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(tablas.CAMPO_NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA, asignatura.getText().toString());

        long idResultante = db.insert(tablas.TABLA_ASIGNATURAS, tablas.CAMPO_NOMBRE_ASIGNATURA, values);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nueva tarea agregada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        db.close();

    }

    private void ConsultarListaPersonas (){

        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();

        atributos atributos = null;
        ListaAtributos= new ArrayList<atributos>();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tablas.TABLA_ASIGNATURAS,null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){

            atributos = new atributos();
            atributos.setAsignatura(cursor.getString(0));

        ListaAtributos.add(atributos);

        }
        obtenerLista();

    }

    private void obtenerLista() {

        ListaInformacion = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i < ListaAtributos.size(); i++){

            ListaInformacion.add(ListaAtributos.get(i).getAsignatura());
        }

        AdapterLista adapter = new AdapterLista(getActivity(),ListaInformacion);
        ListViewPersonas.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

clase adapter

```
package com.example.estudiantes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterLista extends BaseAdapter {

    Context contexto;
    ArrayList<String> lista;
    private PopupMenu popup;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public AdapterLista(Context contexto, ArrayList<String> lista) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.lista = lista;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)contexto.getSystemService(contexto.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     final View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.elementolista,null);

        TextView asignatura = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.textasignatura);
        Button boton  = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.boton);
        asignatura.setText(lista.get(position));

        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                popup = new PopupMenu(contexto, v);
                MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menulist, popup.getMenu());
                popup.show();
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {

                            case R.id.Editar:

                                break;

                            case R.id.Eliminar:

                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        return vista;
    }
}
```

Comment: Primero que nada te recomiendo que comiences a usar ROOM que es una abstracción que te facilita el uso de SQLite, respecto a tu problema puedes agregar al constructor de tu adaptador una interface que servirá como comunicación de tu actividad donde declaras el adaptador y los eventos del adaptador. Te mando este link que puede darte una idea.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes intentar es crear una interface que comunique tu adapter con tu activity, de este modo cuando ejecutas la acción de tu boton ( eliminar y/o editar)que se encuentra en tu adapter llame y ejecute una función que esta en tu activity. Te muestro el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public class AdapterLista extends BaseAdapter {
    public interface OnListItemClickListener {
      void delete(String item);
      void edit(String item);
    }

    private OnListItemClickListener listener;


    public setListener(OnListItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    ........// Todas las cosas normales que tienes en tu adapter

     @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 final View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.elementolista,null);

    TextView asignatura = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.textasignatura);
    Button boton  = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.boton);
    asignatura.setText(lista.get(position));

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            popup = new PopupMenu(contexto, v);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menulist, popup.getMenu());
            popup.show();
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {

                        case R.id.Editar:
                            listener.edit(asignature.getText().toString())
                            break;

                        case R.id.Eliminar:
                            listener.delete(asignature.getText().toString())
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
    });

    return vista;
    }
}
```

y en tu activity tendrias algo como esto.

```
public class asignaturas extends Fragment implements OnListItemClickListener{

 ..............//Todo tu código normal
 @Override
 public void delete(String item){
      //Aqui va tu codiGo para eliminar
 }

 @Override
 public void edit(String item){
      //Aqui va tu codiGo para editar
 }

}
```

Espero te ayude :D